# Transparent background in processing for Android

Tags: android, background, processing

I am working with an **augmented** reality app, I would like to overlay processing graphics over the camera captures.

However the processing graphs have always a **gray** background. I need to have it `transparent` in order to see only the objects rendered by processing over the `camera capture`. Is there anyway to do it? how should I modify the surface for that purpose. I have tried to put a .png image with transparency as image but I get an error.

**Note:-**(I work in Android Studio) Any help will be appriciated thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: so far I only tried with a background with alpha value but it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can draw the camera image as the background of the sketch:

```
// import android.graphics.Bitmap;

PImage camImg;

void setup(){
  background(0);
  size(300, 300);
}

void draw(){
  background(getCameraImg());

  // ... your AR drawing
}

PImage getCameraImg(){
  // 1. Static example:
  camImg = loadImage("image.png", "png");
  camImg.resize(width, height);

  // 2. Android Bitmap -> PImage conversion:
  // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html
  // http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array
  // https://processing.org/reference/updatePixels_.html

  return camImg;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried something similar and it does not work. I am displaying the camera capture in one FrameLayout, and I overlay another one with the sketch of processing. I tried with a png and it stops with these error: "// Other errors typically mean that the current surface is bad,probably because the SurfaceView surface has been destroyed,but we haven't been notified yet. Log the error to help developers understand why rendering stopped.

Comment: I think there is a problem too, when you put an Image as background, the app crashes always in that case